# Why protractor give me success?

Tags: protractor

```
describe('login', function() {
/*    beforeEach(function() {
        browser.get('http://front.dukender.org.kz/home');
    });*/
    it('empty fields', function() {
        browser.get('http://front.dukender.org.kz/home');
//        element(by.id('user_name')).sendKeys('');
//        element(by.id('password')).sendKeys('');
        element(by.buttonText('Войти')).click();
        element(by.cssContainingText('p', 'Вы ввели неверный логин или пароль'));
        browser.pause();
    });
/*    it('wrong password', function() {
        browser.get('http://front.dukender.org.kz/home');
        element(by.id('user_name')).sendKeys('knursultana@gmail.com');
        element(by.id('password')).sendKeys('qwerty');
        element(by.buttonText('Войти')).click();
        element(by.cssContainingText('p', 'Вы ввели неверный логин или пароль'));
    });
    it('success', function() {
        element(by.id('user_name')).sendKeys('knursultana@gmail.com');
        element(by.id('password')).sendKeys('qwerty123');
        element(by.buttonText('Войти')).click();
        element(by.cssContainingText('span', 'Выход'));
    });*/
});

/*describe('profile', function() {
    it('changeName', function() {
        element(by.cssContainingText('span', 'Настройки')).click();
        element(by.cssContainingText('a', 'Профиль')).click();
//        browser.pause();
    });
});*/
```

I wrote this test. But I don't understand, why in terminal success result. Can you help me? Is it right (my code)? I want to write multiple cases. And how to write the results of the test? To know which case failed

Answer (score 3):

You have no assertions in your tests... so everything passes because you are not checking anything.  Protractor is a test framework, you need a test library for assertions.  Please read http://www.protractortest.org/#/frameworks, or even the full Protractor tutorial again because it seems you are not understanding a very large (and essential) part of this tool.